# Spring boot injection of inherited class

Tags: java, spring, inheritance, spring-boot, inject

I'm developing upon a java core library were change is held to a minimum, it holds a class Foo, where Foo is used by a spring rest interface and autowired into the rest interface.

I have to extend Foo to override one of it's method that is called upon Foo.init(), to alter the initiation a bit.

My FooExtend is autowired from another class in my project, and I'm hoping to get these two to reference the same object, the FooExtend object, but at the moment I get one Foo object and one FooExtend. How should I solve this? Examples below

```
@Component
public class Foo{
  @PostConstruct
  private void init() {
    startStuff();
  }

  protected void startStuff(){
    //Stuff done here
  }
}

@Component
public class FooExtend extends Foo{
  @PostConstruct
  private void init() {
    //Nothing is done here
  }

  @Override
  protected void startStuff(){
    //Different altered stuff is done here
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand your problem. You have two beans, one bean with name "foo" and one bean with name "fooExtend". It seems to me that you should be able to use @Qualifier("fooExtend") or @Qualifier("foo") along with @Autowired on top of reference to Foo to autowire one or another.

Answer (score 0):

Try to exclude the Foo class from scan

```
@ComponentScan(value = {'your.package.here'}, excludeFilters = {
  @ComponentScan.Filter(classes = { Foo.class })
})
```

Comment: I can not do changes like this towards Foo as it is in the Core package and should therefor not be changed to destroy for other projects depending on core. Or should I put it in my own package somewhere?

Comment: You should add this on your spring-boot (not in the core package). So when your app starts the a bean for the Foo.class is not created.

Comment: Cant get that to work, I'm probably to amigous in my definiion of the class, but I get this error when doing that:

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An error occurred while processing a @ComponentScan ANNOTATION type filter:  class com.companyname.projectname.core.Foo is not assignable to interface java.lang.annotation.Annotation`

Comment: A problem with this solution is that core has it's own @ComponentScan, including Foo. So this exclude will probalby only break as it does not find anything.

Comment: If you don't want to register Foo in you Spring context then it is a correct solution. Try specifying filter type: @ComponentScan.Filter(type=FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, value=Foo.class). However it is required that Foo and FooExtend are in different packages so that FooExtend is registered in your Spring context.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 possible answers depending on your requirements:

1) You want to register both Foo and FooExtend in your Spring context.
In such case you can use @Qualifier annotation to inject one instance or another:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("fooExtend")
Foo foo;
```

2) You only want to register FooExtend in your Spring context.

```
@ComponentScan(value = {'your.package.here'}, excludeFilters = {
 @ComponentScan.Filter(type=FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, value=Foo.class))
}
```

However it is required that Foo and FooExtend are in different packages so that FooExtend is NOT exluded by the above filter.

Comment: Solution 2 would be the preferable one, but Foo is in the Spring Context of Core, causing it still to be loaded

Comment: It depends on how you scan/register beans from your core library. If it is @ComponentScan then you can exlude it by means of Filter.

Comment: I was not able to make it work. It gave me the following error:
`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An error occurred while processing a @ComponentScan ANNOTATION type filter: class com.companyname.projectname.core.Foo is not assignable to interface java.lang.annotation.Annotation`